# Regular expression ignore in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

For example there is this line:

```
<a title="best title in the world" href="http://website.com/15661-erko-rhyno/">! Erko_Rhyno !</a>
```

Now my code returns:

```
15661-erko-rhyno/">! Erko_Rhyno !
```

Im using:

```
(?<=\<strong\>\<a title\=\"best title in the world\" href\=\"http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/web\/index\.php\/user\/).*?(?=\<\/a\>\<\/strong\>)
```

Now I need that it would be without `15661-erko-rhyno/">` like this:

```
! Erko_Rhyno !
```

I know why it returns with  `15661-erko-rhyno/">` because I specified only ignore this part:

```
<strong><a title="best title in the world" href="http://www.webste.com/web/index.php/user/
```

But there is the problem now u see this part:

```
15661-erko-rhyno/">`
```

Always changes and I don't know how to ignore this part, I will repeat myself and will provide again the code that I'm suing to ignore characters that I don't need::

```
(?<=\<strong\>\<a title\=\"best title in the world\" href\=\"http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/web\/index\.php\/user\/).*?(?=\<\/a\>\<\/strong\>)
```

Maybe someone could provide example or answer what I should put in order to ignore those lines whats left?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore the > character like

```
\>([^\>]+)\<\/a\>
```

to get `! Erko_Rhyno !` in group(1)

Comment: will select this is as an answer in 9 minutes now it doesn't let me THANKS!